# Execute liquibase SQL query only againt local DB

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot application which uses liquibase to track and version DB changes. I am using xml files where I define the changesSets.

I need to add one insert into statement which I need to execute against the local developer DB.

Is there a way to execute this SQL query adding some kind of condition so that it gets executed only if the DB is the local one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use liquibase contexts for that.

Just specify the liquibase context in your local `application.properties` file:

```
spring.liquibase.contexts=local
```

And specify the context to the needed changeSet:

```
<changeSet id=“foo” author=“bar” context=“local”>
    — logic for local db 
</changeSet>
```